# Apply & %in% too being slow in r

Tags: r, performance, loops

I have a data frame and a list:

1- a data frame with the start and end of the interval numeric (~ 4000 rows)

```
start     end
   1      50000
 100000  150000
 98000   100000
  ...      ...
```

2.- a list of numeric values (10039 in length)

`value.list = c(4999, 1432, 120000, 400000, ...)`

**Q. I would like to count the number of values in the `value.list` appear in the range specific in `data.frame.1`.**

For example, I want to know *"how many values in the `value.list` appear in the interval of 1 and 50000?"* Currently there are 4 example values in the value.lists and that value `4999` and `1432` will appear in the interval of 1 and 50000 - so the counts will be (at least) two.

My current code:

```
count_function <- function(x){
    expanded <- unlist(Map(":", x$start, x$end), recursive = F)
    return (sum(value.list %in% expanded))}
answer <- apply(data.frame.1, 1, count_function)
```

**This function works, but it's VERY VERY SLOW!! especially when there are ~4000 rows. How can i improve this function to make it faster?**

Comment: `value.list = c(4999, 1432, 120000, 400000, ...)` -- the right hand side of that is a vector rather than a list, so I find your terminology somewhat confusing in the context of R. Your code seems to be expanding pairs of endpoints to whole ranges, which is surely inefficient. Checking if a number is between 1 and 1,000,000 shouldn't require the creation of 1,000,000 items in memory. Those expansions are extravagant. Use pairs of `<=` rather than `%in%`

Comment: @JohnColeman rightt... Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do programmers nowadays still learn about time complexity?

Comment: @qwr to be honest, not really..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to expand into ranges and use `%in%`. That is dramatically inefficient if `end - start` is large. Instead, use inequalities:

```
df <- data.frame(start = c(10,20,30), end = c(15,35,50))
vals <- c(13,14,24,30,31,40,45,48,49,52)
apply(df,1,function(row) sum(row[1] <= vals & vals <= row[2]))
```

which evaluates to `2 3 6`

Here `df` is

```
start end
1    10  15
2    20  35
3    30  50
```

and the counts of `2,3,6` are readily verified.

With no assumptions about `start` and `end`, I don't think that you can do much better than this, but improvements could be made if e.g. `df$start` is always in sorted order.

Answer (score 2):

The OP's main issue was the speed of his solution.  So that's an important factor in determining the appropriateness of a solution.  We can use toy data to confirm we will get the right answer, but we need real data to evaluate which answer is best.

As an example, here's a tidyverse solution, using @JohnColeman's toy data.

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- tibble(start=c(10, 20, 30), end=c(15, 35, 50))
values <- c(13,14,24,30,31,40,45,48,49,52)

test %>% 
  expand(nesting(start, end), Value=values) %>% 
  group_by(start, end) %>% 
  summarise(N=sum(start <= Value & Value <= end), .groups="drop")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  start   end     N
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1    10    15     2
2    20    35     3
3    30    50     6
```

So it gives the same answers as John Coleman's code.  But which solution serves the OP best?

Generate some real data:

```
startEnd <- tibble(
              start=sample(seq(1000, 1000000, 1000), 4000, replace=TRUE),
              end=start + 100*ceiling(runif(4000, min=5, max=1000))
)
values <- ceiling(runif(10039, min=500, max=10000000))
```

Now test them using `microbenchmark`.  First, using `apply`

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark({
  apply(startEnd,1,function(row) sum(row[1] <= values & values <= row[2]))
},
times=10)

Unit: milliseconds 
     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval                                                                                                 
28.29608 28.68261 31.73897 29.51836 33.62947 46.79597    10
```

Now using `tidyverse`.

```
microbenchmark({
startEnd %>% 
  expand(nesting(start, end), Value=values) %>% 
  group_by(start, end) %>% 
  summarise(N=sum(start <= Value & Value <= end), .groups="drop")
},
times=10)

Unit: seconds
                                                                                                                                                                                          
      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 9.220095 9.523935 9.657978 9.592739 9.905819 10.0541    10
```

Note the change of units in the results summary.

So `apply` beats `tidyverse` by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Nice answer. The benchmarks are informative.